# .to_xml not working properly when using Active Model Serializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, active-model-serializers

I'm trying to render an xml response on my rails API using mime response.
the code is like this :

`respond_to do |format| format.xml { render xml: @records.to_xml, status: :ok } format.json { render json: @records, status: :ok } end`

I'm using serializer on @records to properly shows the record needed. however it is only working on json format and not to XML format.

btw my serializer uses relation and im also using pagy to paginate the record.

I have both activemodel-serializer and activemodel-serializer-xml in my gemfile

sample: @records = Model.where(conditions)

result in XML format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <models type="array">
    <model>
        <id type="integer">1</id>
        <name type="string"> name1 </name>
        <status type="string"> active </status>
    </model>
</models>
```

result in JSON format: `{ id: 1, name: 'name1', model_associate: [ { id: 1, name: 'ma_name1' } ] }`

Expected output :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <models type="array">
    <model>
        <id type="integer">1</id>
        <name type="string"> name1 </name>
        <model_associates type="array">
           <model_associate>
              <id type="integer">1</id>
              <name type="string">ma_name1</name>
           <model_associate>
        </model_associates>
    </model>
</models>
```

Im using rails 7, ruby 3.0

Comment: Not working is a very vague description. What happens instead? Is there an error message, what does it say?

Comment: no error, however, the result were records from parent table, I have serializer for parent table with 'has many ( associate )' that includes children records. it's working fine on render JSON format but in XML seems the serializer didn't take effect.

Comment: Add the information to the question -- comments are not permanent

Answer (score 0):

**Answer 1:**

01 to_xml can be used after installing activemodel-serializers-xml  in your rails environment.

02 activemodel-serializers-xml can be installed in two ways

a) `gem install activemodel-serializers-xml` (But did not work in rails environment)

b) To work in rails environment add in your Gemfile or use bundle

```
  bundle add activemodel-serializers-xml
  bundle install
```

03 Create your Model and Include ActiveModel::Serializers::Xml

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  include ActiveModel::Serializers::Xml
end
```

04 Create you Controller and go to your favourite method eg. say 'show', find user and use to_xml as below.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user = User.find(1)
    xml = @user.to_xml
    puts xml # You may check by printing on console.
    render xml: xml # render plain: xml
  end
end
```

**Answer 2:** As long as `activemodel-serializers-xml` is installed and recognised by your environment, it will work. To test it directly on console, use following program. save it as 'xmltest.rb' and run on console as:

```
  ruby xmltest.rb
```

If it does not work then activemodel-serializers-xml is not installed properly.

Code follows: Modify it for your database and Table

```
   require "active_record"
   require "activemodel-serializers-xml"

   ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
     :adapter => "mysql2",
     :host => "127.0.0.1",
     :username => "root",
     :password => "",
     :database => "test",
   )

   class User < ActiveRecord::Base #ApplicationRecord
     include ActiveModel::Serializers::Xml
   end

   user = User.find(1)
   xml = user.to_xml

   puts xml
```

Comment: restart rails server

Comment: somehow adding (include ActiveModel::Serializers::Xml) in UserController also works

Comment: unfortunately mate, this doesn't work

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: I have explained it better way. I tested it with rails 7.0.6 , ruby 3.2.2